# Menu pages in Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, mezzanine

In Mezzanine / Django, I have several nested pages but only the most deeply-nested page has content. For each intermediate page I simply want to show a menu of its immediate children. For example, given the layout:

```
Chapter 1
    Section 1.1
        Subsection 1.1.1
        Subsection 1.1.2
    Section 1.2
        Subsection 1.2.1
Chapter 2
    Section 2.1
        Subsection 2.1.1
```

The page slugged as `chapter-1` should just show a list of

```
* Section 1.1
* Section 1.2
```

I can do this by creating custom templates for each Chapter and Section containing:

```
{% load pages_tags %}
{% page_menu "pages/menus/chapter_menu.html" %}
```

where `chapter_menu.html` is my menu template:

```
{% load pages_tags %}
<ul>
{% for page in page_branch %}
{% if page.in_menu %}
{% if page.is_current_child %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
</li>
{% else %}
{% page_menu page %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, each template name (e.g. `pages/chapter-1.html`) has to match the slug of the page it refers to, so I need to duplicate these templates for every chapter and every section.

What is the correct way to do this without all the duplication of templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a template for every menu. i solved this by using the tree.html and my_menu.html from [enter link description here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html)

So i just replaced menus/tree.html with:

```
{% load i18n future pages_tags %}
{% spaceless %}
{% page_menu "pages/menus/my_menu.html" %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

and added menus/my_menu.html:

```
{% load pages_tags %}
{% for page in page_branch %}
    {% if page.is_current_child %}
    <a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if page.is_current_or_ascendant %}
        {% if page.has_children_in_menu %}{% page_menu page %}{% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```